# Create a Text with a special structure

Tags: android, text, structure

Is there a way to write and save a Text with a special structure ? So I want for example sth like this in my Text File :

```
This is a
structured
Text in 
android
```

There should be also Tabs etc. I thought to make a Word Document but cant find a solution ...

Comment: use `\n` for next line, `\t` for tabs. Like: "This is a\nstructured" (note the `\n` before "structured")

Comment: But this is not Working in Strings isnt it ?

Comment: do you mean in strings.xml? yes, it works.

Comment: use html tag in string.xml to format text.

Comment: This works for me: `<string name="no_web">At the moment, the Internet connectivity is absent.\nThe data will be sent later.</string>`